# Margins mirrored in thesis template

Tags: margins, templates, double-sided, thesis

I'm using the [LaTeX thesis template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) and I'm trying to set the margins. The guidelines for writing my thesis states this about the margins:

> - Printed double-sided on white A4 paper within the range 70g/m2 to
>     100g/m2;
> - Margins should be set to ‘Mirrored’ The outside margin should be 4cm
>     (1.5”); all other margins 2cm (0.75”)

The thesis template set the margins with this code:

```
\setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.75in}  % top margin
                        { 0.75in}  % right margin
                        { 0.75in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot
```

I need to alter this code so it fit with what my thesis writing guidelines state. I tried the code below, but this failed:

```
\usepackage[left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,bindingoffset=0.75in,headheight=20pt,headsep=0.25in,footheight=9pt,footsep=0.3in]{geometry}
```

How can I set my margins to fit with my thesis guidelines?

Comment: You mean `\usepackage[inner=0.75in,outer=1.5in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in,bindingoffset=0.1in,headheight=20pt,headsep=0.25in,footheight=9pt,footsep=0.3in]{geometry}` ?

Comment: Out of interest, why did you choose *this* template out of three choices?

Comment: You're right in not wanting to use `vmargin`; you also have to remove the call to the package.

Comment: somehow related [Changing a4paper to letterpaper](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253403)

Comment: @Johannes_B I can't actually remember why I chose that template. Do you not think it's the best choice?

Comment: Haha, sorry. I was just laughing out very loud. building a mechanical super-shark, deep-frying kittens, using this template, crossing a red traffic light. Pretty much that order.

Comment: Just an FYI: The next release of the template will use package `geometry`.

Comment: @Johannes_B I had to stop reading after `\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}]`.