# Switching paper size in amsart

Tags: document-classes, paper-size, preamble, amsart

Consider the following LaTeX Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

The generated PDF has `US Letter, Portrait (8.50 × 11.00 inch)` as its letter size, but I specifically requested it to be `a4paper`. However, adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` fixes the issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

The paper size is now `A4, Portrait (8.27 × 11.69 inch)`.

### Questions

1. What is causing the effect described above?
2. Should the paper size be changed by adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` or is there a more standard way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Actually, I cannot reproduce this problem. If I use `\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}`, I get a PDF with 210 x 297 mm which is A4. The option `a4paper` is also documented in the package documentation. Anyways, the paper size can also be set using the package `geometry`. The package `graphicx` is not meant for this.

Comment: @JasperHabicht this is by design (including graphicx feature)

Comment: This is in a way a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524987/proper-way-to-switch-paper-size  The answer given there also provides some other options that will help change the paper size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that you have the site default set to US Letter, `[a4paper]` sets the text block for typesetting to A4 but can not (or at least does not) set the pdf media size until it knows which back end is in force, typically `graphicx` or `hyperref` or `geometry` will force a back end option. If you are loading one just for this, `geometry` is perhaps the most natural.